# Problem with Indy and SSL on Delphi 10.4 Sydney

Tags: delphi, ssl, indy

I'm facing a problem when compiling an application that uses Indy and SSL,

The `TIdTCPClient` send client certificate in order to be validated. The same code runs fine on Delphi 10.3 but fails on Delphi 10.4. The callback method from SSL handler is not called and the server closes the connection gracefully because no ssl is negotiated.

```
  FClient                         := TIdTCPClient.Create( nil );
  FClient.Host                    := trim(FAddress);
  FClient.Port                    := FPuerto;
  FClient.ConnectTimeout          := 10000;

  FIdSSLIOHandler                         := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create( nil );
  FIdSSLIOHandler.OnGetPassword           := SSLGetPassword;
  FIdSSLIOHandler.SSLOptions.Mode         := sslmClient;
  FIdSSLIOHandler.SSLOptions.Method       := FSSLMetodo;
  FIdSSLIOHandler.SSLOptions.VerifyDepth  := 0;

  FIdSSLIOHandler.SSLOptions.RootCertFile := SSLArchivoCertificadoCA;
  FIdSSLIOHandler.SSLOptions.CertFile     := SSLArchivoCertificado;
  FIdSSLIOHandler.SSLOptions.KeyFile      := SSLArchivoClavePrivada;

  if( SSLDebug )then
  begin
     FIdSSLIOHandler.OnStatusInfo := SSLCallBack;
  end;

  FCLient.IOHandler := FIdSSLIOHandler;
```

In Delphi 10.3 I get this lines in OnStatusInfo

```
18/01/2021 16:39:44.836 SSL status: "before/connect initialization"
18/01/2021 16:39:44.836 SSL status: "before/connect initialization"
18/01/2021 16:39:44.836 SSL status: "SSLv2/v3 write client hello A"
18/01/2021 16:39:44.868 SSL status: "SSLv3 read server hello A"
18/01/2021 16:39:44.868 SSL status: "SSLv3 read server certificate A"
18/01/2021 16:39:44.868 SSL status: "SSLv3 read server key exchange A"
18/01/2021 16:39:44.868 SSL status: "SSLv3 read server done A"
18/01/2021 16:39:44.868 SSL status: "SSLv3 write client key exchange A"
18/01/2021 16:39:44.868 SSL status: "SSLv3 write change cipher spec A"
18/01/2021 16:39:44.883 SSL status: "SSLv3 write finished A"
18/01/2021 16:39:44.883 SSL status: "SSLv3 flush data"
18/01/2021 16:39:45.086 SSL status: "SSLv3 read finished A"
18/01/2021 16:39:45.086 SSL status: "SSL negotiation finished successfully"
18/01/2021 16:39:45.086 SSL status: "SSL negotiation finished successfully"
18/01/2021 16:39:45.086 Cipher: name = DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA; description = DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
; bits = 256; version = TLSv1/SSLv3;
```

But in Delphi 10.4 I only get

```
18/01/2021 16:33:07.228   10.215.134.243 Connection Closed Gracefully.
```

Comment: Where are you setting `FIdSSLIOHandler.PassThrough=False`? That log implies there is no TLS negotiation even being started. So, either 1) you are missing `PassThrough=False` and the server kicks you out when `TIdTCPClient` tries to send non-TLS data when TLS data is expected; or 2) `FIdSSLIOHandler` is failing to load the OpenSSL DLLs, and the connection gets closed.  Either condition should be raising an exception into your code. please provide a [mcve] showing everything you are doing between the initial setup (which you have shown) up to the time of the error (which you have not shown)

Comment: Remy, The same code is compiled in delphi 10.3 and in delphi 10.4. Both executables are placed in the same folder with the same version of libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll, 1.0.1c. No exception are raised. I will try to provide a case, but I don't have the server part where we connect to.

Comment: Remy, The problem is still in Delphi 10.4 Sydney. I have downloaded the latest version from Github and compiled the project with that sources and the problem is solved. If I use the sources from the latest version of 10.4 the problem raises.

Comment: You still haven't answered my earlier questions. And earlier, you said you were using OpenSSL 1.0.1c, why such an old version? Is that still the case now? You should be using 1.0.2u at a minimum, which you can get from https://github.com/IndySockets/OpenSSL-Binaries.  Or, if you want to use OpenSSL 1.1.x, use [this SSLIOHandler](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/pull/299) instead.

Comment: Remy, OpenSSL version 1.0.2q. I compiled the same code with Delphi 10.3 and runs, I compiled with 10.4.2 does not run. I downloaded the latest version of Indy from github, and replace the source of Indy in Delphi 10.4.2 and compiled the project using the new sources and runs. I don't know where the problem is, but not in my source code.